# Exiting out of nested switch statement to outer switch statement

Tags: java, nested, switch-statement

I've created a menu in Java wherein each option has another menu. I want to know if I can exit from the inner menu back to the main menu.

Edit: Added Main Menu options

```
System.out.println("Main Menu");
    System.out.println("1. Hourly Employees");
    System.out.println("2. Salary Employees");
    System.out.println("3. Commission Employees");
    System.out.println("4. Weekly Calculations");
    System.out.println("5. Exit Program");
while(true){
    switch(choice){
        case 1: 
            HourlyEmployeeChoice HEC = new HourlyEmployeeChoice();
            //HourlyEmployeeChoice is a class with HEmployeeMenu() method 
            HEC.HEmployeeMenu();
            break;
        //case 2-4: to be added later
        case 5:
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
            System.exit(0);
    }
    }
```

This is my main menu.  I only wrote the code for the first option and the option to exit.

```
public void HEmployeeMenu(){
    while(true){
        //submenu options
        int hourlyChoice = userChoice.nextInt();
            switch(hourlyChoice) {
                case 1: 
                    //code
                    break;
                case 2: 
                    //code
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //code
                    break;
                case 4: //exit submenu
                    return;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Please make a valid selection"); 
            }
    }
}
```

This is the method I put my second switch statement inside. Choosing option 4 (exit submenu) refreshes to the submenu rather than the main menu. I think what's causing this is the while loop I have for the submenu.  I don't want to take this option off though, because I want to be able to continue making choices after doing cases 1-3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem you are having is

```
while(true){
  // HERE
  switch(choice){
```

You need to add code to get the `choice` again, otherwise it will always be whatever you first entered.

That is move the main menu display and `choice` input to something like

```
while(true){
  System.out.println("Main Menu"); // <-- Added based on your edit.
  System.out.println("1. Hourly Employees");
  System.out.println("2. Salary Employees");
  System.out.println("3. Commission Employees");
  System.out.println("4. Weekly Calculations");
  System.out.println("5. Exit Program");
  int choice = userChoice.nextInt(); // <-- HERE
  switch(choice){
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! This sort of worked.  When I exit out of the submenu and back to the main menu, the options for the main menu don't appear again.  I can type in a number (1-5) and get the command for that number from the main menu but I'd prefer for the main menu options to appear again after exiting the submenu.

Comment: @SeverelyConfused Perhaps you should add that display then. You didn't post it here, but it would probably go after `while (true)` and before `int choice = userChoice.nextInt();`

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted.  I tried that before but it didn't work.  I think I must have put main menu options after int choice.  Thank you!